# Scheduling Windows threads to run with high accuracy timing?

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi, scheduled-tasks

I'm asking this in a general sense without a specific language in mind.

What I want to be able to do is have a thread run every 100ms with a high accuracy. It seems that the highest accuracy I'm able to get using normal threads (in a quick test application) is about 5ms or so. The thread takes about 10ms to perform its task.

Basically, is there any way to ask Windows to schedule my thread with at certain delays? (To the best of its ability, I'm aware it's not a realtime operating system)

Comment: Is the type of task you're performing one that absolutely needs 100ms timing or does it just need to *average* that timing over the long term - i.e. is it the sort of system where you can measure and adjust timings so that overall the average comes out well but the individual timings may be a little out?

Comment: Maybe a [waitable timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms687008%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) would be worth investigating .... leave the thread running and let it manage its frequency by waiting on the timer object.

Comment: Threads are normally eligible to run at the clock interrupt rate, 15.625 msec by default.  Sounds like some program on your machine is already messing with this if you get 5 msec, it is not uncommon.  You tinker with it by calling timeBeginPeriod().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, probably the best you can do is to use a [multimedia timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd742877.aspx). These are the platform's high resolution timers.